# android deep doze setalarmclock で no network conecction になってしまう

Tags: android

androidアプリでdeep doze時にsetalarmclockで起きた後に、wifi接続できません。

https://qiita.com/FumihikoSHIROYAMA/items/b1d6dbda120462d0e209

などによると、setalarmclock起こした場合はネットワーク接続可能と認識しています。
ネットワーク接続が完了するのを待つように、WifiInfo.SupplicantStateがcompletedになるまで待つループをもうけてみましたが、completedにはならないようでした。

deep doze になる前にlockを取得することは電池の消耗の観点から避けたいと考えています。ホワイトリストへの登録も同様です。

setalarmclockで起床後にwifiにつなぐにはどうしたら良いでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

起床後にwakelockとwifilockを取得したらwifiにつながりました